# DC Connector for medium voltage PSU output

Tags: dc, dc-motor, connector

I've just built an enclosure for a 240V mains PSU that drives an 800W 0-100V DC spindle motor for a hobby CNC machine. Everything's earthed as appropriate, all looks good, and it works.

But I'm struggling to find a good DC connector for connecting the motor's power cable. I really want a panel-mounted socket, so I can plug in the motor cable - the CNC machine is multi-purpose, so the spindle and its PSU are non-permanent fixtures. Right now, the cable goes through a grommet in the side of the box and is wired straight into the PSU (with a small knot for strain-relief).

When I search for DC power connectors, I find nothing rated above 30V. So, first question: is there a standard DC power connector rated for this sort of job?

Now, I suspect they just sell higher voltage/power connectors as "AC" because that's what people use them for, and that as long as the insulation is ok with the voltage and the conductors can handle the current, then it doesn't really matter.

So I'm thinking of finding some uncommon, polarized 240V mains connector, and just using that. I'm looking something no bigger than an [IEC 60230-2-2 F](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/ATX_PS_back_panel.jpg): any bigger, and I'll need a bigger box! In principle, I could actually use that socket, but it'd be dangerously inviting to a mains plug - boom! I want something less common. But the smaller IEC ones' current ratings are too low.

Are my "use an AC connector" assumptions valid? Are there any connectors which might do the job? This is a home/hobby application, not commercial - but that doesn't mean I'm ok with electrocuting anyone!

**Edit**

No sooner do I hit *Save* on this question, and having spent ages fruitlessly looking for a suitable connector, the [Bulgin Buccaneer](http://www.bulgin.com/products/circular-power-connectors.html) series suddenly decides to leap out from under Google's rock, where it was hiding!  This looks like the tool for the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a week, and I've solved my own problem. My mistake was that I was discounting "Industrial and Automation" applications in my searches on distributor websites (RS, Farnell, etc) and my searches for "DC Power Connector" were swamped with little 12v power jacks.

Once you click "Industrial", all the 200V-600V AC/DC connectors magically appear.

My problem has been solved with [Bulgin Buccaneer](http://www.bulgin.com/products/circular-power-connectors.html) circular connectors. I'm using their 4000 series connector, which takes a small (19mm) panel hole, and is locking, waterproof, beautiful, and of course, reassuringly expensive.